# Do I need to explicitly DROP VIEW in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, create-view

I've read the documentation on creating VIEWs in mysql, and I can't figure out if views are a temporary thing or if they are permanent. If I only want to use them for one session, do I need to manually add a DROP VIEW query to my PHP script, or do views get destroyed when the connection closes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once created, views persist until dropped - Very much like normal tables. They are not dropped when the current connection session ends like temporary tables.

Answer (score 3):

Views are permanent until dropped. If you want a structure that is bound to the users session then perhaps you want **temporary tables**.

Temporary tables are only visible to the connection used to create them, and they disappear once the connection is closed.